# How to check requiriments for unity 3D?

Tags: 11.10

Recently I make an ubuntu oneiric fresh install, but it is deadly slow. My computer is a HP Pavilion AMD Phenome X3 8600 with 3GB RAM and GeForce6150SEnForce430 according to Nvidia x server.

So I make a few reads, and maybe the slowness it is because the HW, but I'm not an expert, but I installed 64 bit and I think should be faster that if I installed 32 bit version, right? so the problem must be something else, Am I right?

My english is far from perfect, I'll hope you can understand. Thanks you all in advance

**Update** 
+ with unity 2D is faster
**Update**
+ The test's result suggest by Kelley gives me yes.

Comment: @raionsulricardo21.  Please consider accepting some answers for your questions.  This will be helpful for other viewers of your question to benefit.  If the answers were not helpful please advise us or edit your question so a better answer can be sought, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the terminal, type:

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

You will get output that will identify capabilities of your graphics card; one of the items (the last in the list, I think) will tell you if you have "Unity 3D Support:" it'll either give you a "Yes" or a "No."

Comment: result on Yes... so the slow is not because of that... right?

Comment: Have you installed Nvidias driver? Search for drivers in the dash.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure it means it'll be fast, but Unity 3D should work on your system; Unity 2D will almost always be faster, though  And 3 GB of RAM really should be enough.  I don't think you'd get any faster with the 32-bit 11.10, either.  Have you gone to System Settings > Additional Drivers to see if there are proprietary drivers available for your Nvidia card?  (If so, you can enable them from that page.)

Answer (score 0):

There won't be any radical difference in performance if you use 64bit or 32bit. Unity is a Compiz plugin, so the requirements will be the same. Your computer is *more* than fast enough. Ubuntu will run with 512MB RAM and a 550MHz CPU, though that's won't be lightning. :)

Try to login using Unity 2D, which you can find by pressing the button next to the password field when you log in. If that is significantly faster, then the cause is your VGA driver, most likely. Otherwise, there is something else.

Sorry about the generic reply, but it's difficult to know based on the information you provide.

Comment: oh no, my bad.. your answer is quite valuable.. I'll try it!. By the way, would you mind to tell me which any other information can I give you to improve the answer... thanks again

Comment: Hey Jo-Erlend Schinstad ! indee, you were right about unity 2d, is faster.. what can I do?