# My Computer System Information

Tags: system-installation

Heres my System Information. Is this ok for the latest ubuntu? Is my processor good enough?
About installing ubuntu, I have 2 partitions and i put my important files in 2nd Drive (Drive D:), after installing ubuntu, does all files will be erased?

Operating System: Windows XP Professional (5.1, Build 2600) Service Pack 3

```
       Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
```

System Manufacturer: LENOVO

```
   System Model: 3000 C100
           BIOS: LENOVO BIOS Rev: 1.0
      Processor: Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU  230   @ 1.60GHz (2 CPUs)
         Memory: 1016MB RAM
      Page File: 638MB used, 3327MB available
DirectX Version: DirectX 9.0c (4.09.0000.0904)
```

Comment: Boot from live cd and check unity /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p     http://askubuntu.com/questions/69466/how-to-check-requiriments-for-unity-3d

Comment: Maybe you can use gnome-fallback inside of unity. Less requirements, but less cute things too.

Comment: Currently installing Ubuntu 13.04
I'm in the process of Running post-istallation trigger update-notifier-common and its taking too much time.

ubuntu CRON[30150]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))

ubuntu CRON[30199]: (root) CMD (  cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)

ubuntu CRON[30219]: (root) CMD (start -q anacron || :)

ubuntu CRON[30299]: (root) CMD (  cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)

ubuntu CRON[30380]: (root) CMD (  cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)

--stuck in here--

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should be usable on that system, depending on your graphics card. Personally I would use [lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) or [xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) because those run faster on older systems. Be very careful when partitioning. My advice would be to get a a second hard drive. It has saved my a lot of pain for the little that it cost me.

Comment: Or instead of lubuntu or xumbuntu install gnome-shell and use Gnome classic environment. I have done so on very similar pc and it works very well.

Comment: I'm already installing Ubuntu 13.04 and still its ongoin.
I'm in the process of Running post-istallation trigger update-notifier-common and it has this kind of command running.

Comment: this taking too much time.

ubuntu CRON[30150]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))

ubuntu CRON[30199]: (root) CMD (  cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)

ubuntu CRON[30219]: (root) CMD (start -q anacron || :)

ubuntu CRON[30299]: (root) CMD (  cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)

ubuntu CRON[30380]: (root) CMD (  cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)

--stuck in here--